# Specify the number of columns read_csv is applied to

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

Is it possible to pass column indices to read_csv?

I am passing many CSV files to read_csv with different header names so rather than specifying names I wish to use column indices.

Is this possible?

```
df.list <- lapply(myExcelCSV, read_csv, skip = headers2skip[i]-1)
```

Comment: I'm tempted to edit "indexes" to "indices" but will refrain ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Alternatively, you can use a compact string representation
>             where each character represents one column: c = character, i
>             = integer, n = number, d = double, l = logical, f = factor, D
>             = date, T = date time, t = time, ? = guess, or ‘_’/‘-’ to
>             skip the column.

If you know the *total* number of columns in the file you could do it like this:

```
my_read <- function(..., tot_cols, skip_cols=numeric(0)) {
   csr <- rep("?",tot_cols)
   csr[skip_cols]  <- "_"
   csr <- paste(csr,collapse="")
   read_csv(...,col_types=csr)
}
```

If you don't know the total number of columns in advance you could add code to this function to read just the first line of the file and count the number of columns returned ...

FWIW the `skip` argument might not do what you think it does (it skips rows rather than selecting/deselecting columns): as I read `?readr::read_csv()` there doesn't seem to be any convenient way to skip and/or include particular columns (by name or by index) except by some *ad hoc* mechanism such as suggested above; this might be worth a feature request/discussion on the `readr` issues list? (e.g. add `cols_include` and/or `cols_exclude` arguments that could be specified by name or position?)

Comment: might need `scan (what=character(), sep=[something])` instead, as `count.fields()` doesn't seem to have an `n_max` argument? Or `readLines(n=1)` passed to `count.fields()` ?

Comment: Hi @Ben Bolker, thanks for the replied. I do know how many columns (10 for all files) I wish to read in, but in one of the 16 files, read_csv pulls in 13 columns even though there's clearly 10 columns of data. I think there must be some spurious data lying somewhere in the file that's causing the mix up.